# Find most frequently numbers in Python with Pandas from CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have 5 rows with 10 numbers from 1 to 100

```
|   | A | B | C  | D  | E  | F  | G  | H  | I  | J  |
+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 1 | 1 | 3 |  4 |  8 | 12 | 35 | 41 | 70 | 79 | 98 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |  6 |  8 | 13 | 38 | 45 | 72 | 83 | 84 |
| 3 | 7 | 9 | 12 | 41 | 72 | 83 | 84 | 85 | 86 | 98 |
| 4 | 2 | 7 | 12 | 38 | 41 | 51 | 52 | 54 | 68 | 70 |
| 5 | 1 | 3 |  4 |  8 | 13 | 26 | 38 | 54 | 57 | 73 |
+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

How can find most frequently 2 or more numbers?

For example:

1. In 1st and 5th row have 1, 3, 4, 8
2. In 1st ,2nd, 5th have 3, 4, 8
3. In 2nd and 5th have 3, 4, 8, 13
4. In 3th and 4th row have 7, 12

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy and scipy to find the mode.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

nums = np.array(your_array)

mode = stats.mode(nums)
print(mode[0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Granted there could be more than one number with the max count, you could leave off the `.idxmax` to see all of the counts.

```
df.unstack().value_counts().idxmax()
```